# Relationship in Laravel-5.6

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have three tables like below.

```
posts
    _id   - integer
    name - string

sentences
    _id      - integer
    post_id - integer
    name    - string

translations (word by word)
    _id          - integer
    post_id     - integer
    sentence_id - integer
    word_id     - integer
    name        - string
```

In `PostController.php` I am trying to fetch data like below

```
return Post::with(['sentences', 'sentences.translations'])->limit(2)->get();
```

I have function in `post.php` model is like below

```
protected $primaryKey = '_id';
public function sentences()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\sentence', 'post_id','_id');
}
```

I have function in `sentences.php` model is like below

```
protected $primaryKey = '_id';
public function translations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\translation', 'sentence_id','_id');
}
```

I would like to fetch posts along with sentences and translations.

I can fetch post and sentences but I am facing issue while I am trying to fetch translations.

I am getting all the `translations` which `sentence_id` is matched with `id`of  `sentences` table, but `post_id` is not matching with the current post `id` of `post` table.

Comment: What issue are you facing? Do you mean `Post::with('sentences.translations')->get()`?

Comment: Your `translations` relationship is correct, but somehow Laravel uses it with different columns.

Comment: You haven't overridden the `getForeign` function in the sentence model have you?

Comment: Thanks @JonasStaudenmeir. I edited my post.

Comment: Thanks @DigitalDrifter. I edited my post.

Comment: Are your primary keys named `_id`?

Comment: Thanks @DigitalDrifter. Yes, primary keys named `_id`.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you've named your primary keys any thing other than `id`, you need to set the primary key name on each model:

```
class Post extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = '_id';
}
```

Match your relations to the correct name also:

```
return $this->hasMany(Sentence::class, 'post_id','_id');
```

Comment: Thanks @DigitalDrifter. Actually I set the primary key name on each model like this `protected $primaryKey = '_id';`  but I forgot to mention here. My issue is like this ... I am getting all the translations which `sentence_id` is matched with `id` of  `sentences` table, but `post_id` is not matching with the current post `id` of `post` table.

Comment: In that case it seems you've correctly setup the relations, I'm curious what does `$post->getForeignKey()` return?

Comment: Thanks @DigitalDrifter. `$post->getForeignKey()` returns `post_id`. Thanks.